# Amd Apu not saving preferences

Tags: ati, amd-processor

i don't know why after i poweroff my computer, cpu(A4 4355M) resets it's preferences.
I found that my apu has pstate 6 (900Mhz) and boost states disabled (by default?), so i use TurionPowerControl to enable them (and undervolt a bit pstate 6), but if a poweroff my computer everything resets. If i reboot, instead, everything stays as i set it.
I also tried to set everything on boot but i don't know how to refresh cpufreq(whitout reboot) so to use new frequencies in indicator-cpufreq.

Cpupower out: http://oi62.tinypic.com/24v1glx.jpg

TurionPowerControl out: http://oi61.tinypic.com/23js6tj.jpg

Any ideas? Thank you all.